# python - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lock'

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, types, attributeerror

As part of my unit testing procedure i'm evaluating the type of a variable which has been returned from a certain method. The method returns a variable of type 'thread.lock' and I would like to test for this in the same way I test for variables of type 'str' or 'int' etc

> This is the example carried out in the python 2.7.6 shell

```
>>> import threading, thread
>>> mylock = threading.Lock()
>>> type(mylock)
<type 'thread.lock'>
>>> type(mylock) is thread.lock

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    type(mylock) is thread.lock
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lock'
```

> I expected it to return True as shown in the second example

```
>>> myint = 4
>>> type(myint)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(myint) is int
True
>>>
```

Please any solutions on how to get around this will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use the `isinstance()` function. `isinstance(mylock, type(threading.Lock()))` returns `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `thread.lock` use `thread.LockType`:

```
>>> import threading, thread
>>> mylock = threading.Lock()
>>> type(mylock)
<type 'thread.lock'>
>>> thread.LockType
<type 'thread.lock'>
>>> type(mylock) is thread.LockType
True
```

But it is preferable to use `isinstance()`:

```
>>> isinstance(mylock, thread.LockType)
True
```

Comment: Low-level thread API on Python 3.X is called `_thread`. So you can do `import _thread` and check `type( _thread.LockType )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isinstance()` function instead.

```
>>> import threading, thread
>>> mylock = threading.Lock()
>>> type(mylock)
<type 'thread.lock'>
>>> isinstance(mylock, type(threading.Lock()))
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hugo Sousa. This solution works as well but I'll pick the answer given by @mhawke because yours came second. Cheers!